# How do I extract text under a specific header which starts with a certain set of words

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape text in an H2 tag under a header which starts with "benefits of" ...so it could be like "benefits of toys" or "benefits of cups" etc.

The html code is:

```
<h2 class="DrugOverview__title___1OwgG">Benefits of Toys</h2>
```

The code I've used until now is

```
        benfit = soup.find('h2',text='Benefits of')
        q = benefit.get_text(strip=True)
```

How do I solve it?
Also keep in mind the h2 class cant be used to scrape in this situation(due to other issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use regex to get some specific string

I used `strs` as input html content

Use the below code:

```
import re
strs = '<h2 class="DrugOverview__title___1OwgG">Benefits of Toys</h2><h2 class="DrugOverview__title___1OwgG">Benefits of kids</h2>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(strs, 'html.parser')
pattern = re.compile(r'Benefits of')
benefit =  soup.findAll(text = pattern)
print(benefit)
```

Output:

```
['Benefits of Toys', 'Benefits of kids']
```